# How to change screen size from user input value

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage, aspect-ratio

I have one requirement to display image into imageview with aspect ratio from user input dimension. If the user enter the `width = 2000, height =500`, but my image size is `350x199`. How can i fit the aspect ratio of the image into user input. If user enters the 2000 then i need to keep the iPad screen width is 2000 then only i can keep aspect ratio. How can i do this?

```
imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 350, 199)];
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details, or some examples?

Comment: I'm placing one sofa into my room. So, i'm checking does it fit or not particular size of the room. For example if sofa size width is 350 & height is 199. But user enter room dimension width is 1500 & height is 800. So, here my screen width need to change width to 1500 then i need to place the sofa image with aspect ration from the screen

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv: can you understand?

Comment: Have you tried solution from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you:

```
//input data
CGSize screenSize;
CGSize enteredRoomSize;
CGSize originalImageSize;

//ratio calculation
CGFloat widthRatio = screenSize.width / enteredRoomSize.width;
CGFloat heightRatio = screenSize.height / enteredRoomSize.height;
CGFloat minRatio = MIN(widthRatio, heightRatio);

//results calculation
CGSize roomViewSize = CGSizeMake(enteredRoomSize.width * minRatio, enteredRoomSize.height * minRatio);
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(originalImageSize.width * minRatio, originalImageSize.height * minRatio);
```

If you want to use different ratios for width and height use the following code:

```
//input data
CGSize screenSize;
CGSize enteredRoomSize;
CGSize originalImageSize;

//ratio calculation
CGFloat widthRatio = screenSize.width / enteredRoomSize.width;
CGFloat heightRatio = screenSize.height / enteredRoomSize.height;

//results calculation
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(originalImageSize.width * widthRatio, originalImageSize.height * heightRatio);
```

Comment: what is the value of screensize?

Comment: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size or self.view.frame.size. Probably the second one is better.

Comment: I have 2 UITextField for x(width), y(height). If user enters 1000 width, shall i directly apply 1000 to CGFloat widthRatio = self.view.frame.size.width / 1000 ???

Comment: Yes. You can use any data. This code will scale image.

Comment: And i have UIImageView to displays the array of images imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 350, 199)]; how can i apply the ratio to CGRectMake ???

Comment: CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
    frame.size = imageSize;
    imgView.frame = frame;

Comment: originalImageSize.width means 359 from imgView??

Comment: then where should i use roomViewSize ?? It's unused variable?

Comment: What is the use of roomViewSize ? where should i use this?

Comment: Room view is view that presents room. You might not use it. I do not know how do you display room. But if you have such view you should use this size. It is always less than screen size. Original image size is size of your image.

Comment: I need to set room size is 100% of screensize. If i enter width is 2000 means i need to set screen ipad width is 2000 (100%). then if my original image width is 500 means i need to display original image 1/4 th from width 2000, i mean 1/4th in iPad width. because now i need to set iPad width is 2000. Does it possible?

Comment: Yes it works. How should it work if you set width - 2000 and height - 500? My solution contains room view that has the same proportions as size entered by user. So room view size in this case is equal to (1024; 256)

Comment: The width is working fine. But the height is not working properly. If my original image size is 350x199 and the room size enter from user is 350x199. The image occupies 100% but the height is not occupying 100%. why?

Comment: That's ok..but why the height is not proportion?

Comment: Because 1024 / 350 != 768 / 199. It's math.

Comment: if i have array of images with different size, what will happen? does the width is work?

Comment: If my room width is 350 and height is 199. Original image width is 350 and height is 199. The width is fitting 100% in the room but the height is not fitting with ratio. Can you please help of find height aspect ratio and fit room size

Comment: @SviatoslavYalymiv: Please give some idea for height ??

Comment: You want make your image full screen?

Comment: yes..based on width & height ratio..Now width is perfect with ratio of room width but height is not proportionally fit based on user enter height...please help this

Comment: My original image size is 350x199 . If user enter room width & height is 1000x500 means, the width ratio should 1/3 approx, the height ratio is 2.5 apporx. Then it should fit in the screen of the ipad like same ratio

Comment: I need width & height ratio of image display based on user enter value of room size

Comment: I have done what you updated the code..But my image is stretching, it's not proper

Comment: That is what i was talking about. Try to draw what do you want

Comment: Can you help me this? Is any method is there to do?

Comment: I tied to help you. But it seems to be wasting the time. Seems like you do not know what do you want. Sorry.

Comment: please refer this article http://www.insidemobileapps.com/2014/07/23/pixel-com-now-has-an-augmented-reality-app-for-online-art-purchases/

Comment: If my room size is 4x2 inch means i need to show the image in ipad with aspect ratio based on 4x2 inch

Comment: Ok. Thats why i added roomViewSize. iPad ratio is fixed 4 x 3

Comment: iPad screen size: 1024 x 768. If user enters 4x2 roomViewSize == (1024, 512). What is wrong?

Comment: what i do like same as article explain without image stretch but my original image should be proportional to user enter value and ipad screen

Comment: It can't be proportional to both.

Comment: How do you imagine it?

Comment: It's not only 4x2, if user enter 5x3 means the width is 5 and height is 3

Comment: Then image will fit height

Comment: The width is perfectly working, but if i use height like your updated code the image is not proper and it's stretching.So, do i need to use only width??

Comment: From your comment, It can't be proportional to both?? what is meant by this?

Comment: It can be proportional to both only if room has the same proportions as iPad: 4 x 3

Comment: You mean different ratio for width & height from your updated code?

Comment: The image is displaying very close to the screen. Is the any way to display image based on distance from user input. If user enter 8ft distance means, shall i display the image based on the distance?

Comment: I need to display my image based on user distance like this app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978402/display-image-on-camera-view-based-on-user-distance